# random testing model in Python

Tags: python, events, testing, random, poisson

I would like to use a Poisson test function, whereby an event occurs or not according to a given probability *p*. Python's *random* module does not seem to have something like this, thus I figured out

- Turn probability *p* into a fraction
- randomly pick an integer.
- Success is smaller - or - equal to the numerator from a range of integers equal to the denominator.

I, however believe that this is not the most efficient piece of code for the given task. I also doubt about its correctness, nonetheless I think it shoud be if *random.randrange(int)* works according to uniform distribution.

```py
def poisson_test(p):

    '''Poisson test with two possible outcomes, where p is success probability'''

    import fractions

    import random

    from decimal import Decimal

    p = Decimal('{0}'.format(p))

    p = fractions.Fraction(p)

    if random.randrange(p.denominator) <= p.numerator :

        return True

    else:

        return False
```

Any suggestions???

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to rethink what you're trying to do.  The Poisson distribution describes how likely you are to observe 0, 1, 2,... occurrences in a fixed interval, given that the process has a specified rate of occurrences.  What you have described is not a Poisson.  If there are two outcomes, success or failure, with a fixed probability of success, you have a Bernoulli random variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is *clearly* not working:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(poisson_test(0.5) for _ in range(10000))
Counter({True: 10000})
```

[`randrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randrange), like vanilla [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range), *excludes* the `stop` argument, so e.g. `randrange(2)` will **never** be `2` and thus the function always returns `True`.

The minimal fix is:

```
if (random.randrange(p.denominator) + 1) <= p.numerator :
```

which gives much more sensible results:

```
>>> Counter(poisson_test(0.5) for _ in range(10000))
Counter({True: 5024, False: 4976})
```

Alternatively, use [`randint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint), which includes both parameters:

```
if random.randint(1, p.denominator) <= p.numerator :
```

But much simpler is this:

```
import random

def poisson_test(p):
    """Poisson test with two possible outcomes, where p is success probability."""
    return random.random() <= p
```

Note double quotes for the docstring and `import` at the start of the program, per [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).